# Hiding immortality

Tags: immortality

So I somehow turned into an immortal (I don't age). (Looking ~25-30)

Naturally, this brings around some problems. After ~10 years of fun, people started making comments on how young I look. I fear that in the next 10 years this will seriously affect me. People will start asking real questions.

I'm planning to disappear. But life today is too connected. I need passports everywhere, money, jobs where people don't ask who I am and going to jail for a longer time could be very problematic.

Any fixes? What do I do?

(Starting point: Central Europe/US/similar, Caucasian male, ~50k€ funds available).

Comment: If you think this is storytelling (off-topic) please consider it's actually a question about real life and not a specific character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't break the law. By much.

Second, teach yourself *minor* forgery. Males can get away with about a 30 year span in age. Make a habit of "going to the gym" religiously, be an open advocate of "male beauty" regimens (skin tighteners, moisturizing, hair coloring). Admit it, embrace it. For you it is actually natural, you don't have to *really* do anything, but you want to give people a reason to think your young look is a matter of discipline and cosmetics, so much so they are jealous of your (faked) willpower. Who can spend 20 hours a week in the frikkin' gym?!?

Well you aren't, you are watching Game of Thrones and playing World of Warcraft, but make sure people *think* you are putting in that gym time.

The minor forgery: Move often, to other cities, and spend about 10 or fifteen years in each. Maybe change jobs a few times. The point is, you want to forge your own IDs: Your driver's license, your birth certificate, a few other things that nobody checks. This isn't identity theft somebody might report: You are effectively stealing your **own** identity.

When you move, reset the clock (and your documents) to your age; 30. Change your driver's license, nobody will look any further.

Eventually you will need to become a new person; you can do this with planning, and find a woman willing to have your child, for pay (yes, they are available, including surrogate mothers). The idea is, you become your own child. This will be expensive. You get married with a prenup, (you don't have to live together), she has the child and you get full custody, you get divorced and she gets the prenup specified settlement. Arrange for your child to be 'abandoned', in infancy, on the doorstep of a firehouse, or whatever.

You have new papers, a new birth certificate and name, a new social security number. Continue living your life for another 20 years; then move and switch to the papers of your child; get a new driver's license, and (barring some fancy new tech being developed) you are good for another 60 years or so. If you like, keep tabs on your child, to see if any of them inherit your immortality.

Answer (score 0):

### Identity theft

This is the one and only solution for your guy. He has to accept people in his life are temporary, he'll far outlive anyone he'll ever like or love and can't be around them for longer than 10 years without rousing suspicion. Granted your character is willing to make that sacrifice it's a matter of gaining the required skills to pull off identity theft, fly under the radar of the authorities and surroundings alike.